# Repeat rows of data frame with different identifier

Tags: r

Can someone please help me with an easy solution for this problem.
E.g. I have a data frame:

```
data<-data.frame(ID=1,Time=1:10,C="A")
```

I want to repeat all rows in the data frame 30 times with a different "ID" for every replicate. E.g. for `ID<-c("1002","1005","1009"...)`
I have gotten up to:

```
new<-data[rep(seq_len(nrow(data)),times=30), ]
```

but I can't figure out how to change the ID for each replicate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear about the length of "ID" vector.

```
ID <- 1002:1030
data$ID <- ID[seq_len(nrow(data))]
data1 <- data[rep(seq_len(nrow(data)),times=30), ]
```

---

Or if we need a cross join

```
library(data.table)
CJ(ID, data$Time, "A")
```

Answer (score 0):

See `?expand.grid`

```
data <- expand.grid(ID = 1:30, Time = 1:10, C = 'A')
```